# How to choose a proper $\lambda$ for LASSO or BPDN problem?

Tags: matrices, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, least-squares

When I deal with the compressed sensing problem, which can be written as:
$min |x|_0 \;\; s.t. \|Ax-y\|^2\le\epsilon$.
And there are some way to solve the problem, such as relaxing it as 
$min \;\lambda|x|_1 + 0.5\|Ax-y\|^2$, which is also referred to LASSO problem.

My problem is that how to choose $\lambda$? I know that bigger $\lambda$ results in more sparse solution. However, actually I don't know the number of non-zero elements in $x$ and how can I choose the correct $\lambda$ for better performance? For example, $\lambda=1$ results in ten non-zero elements, while $\lambda=20$ results in one, and how can I know which is better?

Comment: In general you will hold out some of the data you are using to fit your model. You fit the model on a subset of the data for various values of lambda and use a validation set to see how good your performance is out of sample. You as the model maker need to decide what values of reconstruction error you're willing to tolerate